# how to combine/concat two bags in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have two datasets:

```
A = {uid, url}; B = {uid, url};
```

now I do a `cogroup`:

```
C = COGROUP A BY uid, B BY uid;
```

and I want to change C into {`group AS uid, DISTINCT A.url+B.url`};

My question is how do I do this concatenation of two bags A.url and B.url?

Or to put it differently, how do I do `DISTINCT` on multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be what you're expecting but that's what I understood from your question:

```
C = JOIN A BY uid, B BY uid;
D = DISTINCT C;
```

Concatenation is done the following way:

```
E = FOREACH D GENERATE CONCAT(A::uid,B::uid);
```

Comment: CONCAT operates on strings, not on bags.  
Maybe you meant:  
`define BagConcat datafu.pig.bags.BagConcat();`  
and then  
`BagConcat(A::uid, B::uid)`

Please forgive me, I can't figure out how to do line breaks here.  
The suggestion to end each line with two spaces is bullshit.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = LOAD 'A' using PigStorage() as (uid,url);
B = LOAD 'B' using PigStorage() as (uid,url);
C = JOIN A by uid ,B by uid;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0,CONCAT(A::url,B::url);
E= DISTINCT D;
dump E;
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.