# hadoop pig script - union with condition

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I am entirely new to Pig. I want to union two files A and B using iid field, but I dont want the output has any iids (from B) that A doesn't have. This seems to be simple, but I cannot figure out how to do it correctly.

Here is my sample code that has union only:

```
a = load '$input' as (iid:int, field:chararray, v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
b = load '$data' as (iid:int, field:chararray, v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
out = union onschema a,b;
singled = distinct out;
ordered = order singled by iid;
store ordered into '$output';
```

Below is the sample data with only 3 columns to describe what I expect. Note that fields are actually tab delimited.

Sample data A:

```
1  Name   Tom Linkon
1  Title  Professor
2  Name   Whatever
2  Title  Worker
```

Sample data B:

```
1  City  New York
2  City  Columbus
3  City  Fake fake
4  City  Blah Bla
```

Sample output

```
1  Name   Tom Linkon
1  Title  Professor
1  City   New York
2  Name   Whatever
2  Title  Worker
2  City   Columbus
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you need tuples from a and b to end up in separate tuples or is it ok that they end up in the same tuple when the value of iid matches?

Comment: @Fred I just added sample data A, B and output data samples in my question for clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `COGROUP` to organize records with the same key, but avoid `JOIN`'s undesirable cross-product.  Then `FILTER` by whether the bag with `b`'s records is empty, split back into two relations, and do the `UNION`:

```
a = load '$input' as (iid:int, field:chararray, v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
b = load '$data' as (iid:int, field:chararray, v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
c = COGROUP a BY iid, b BY iid;
c_filt = FILTER c BY NOT IsEmpty(b);
a_new = FOREACH c_filt GENERATE group AS iid, FLATTEN(a);
b_new = FOREACH c_filt GENERATE group AS iid, FLATTEN(b);
out = UNION ONSCHEMA a_new, b_new;
singled = DISTINCT out;
STORE (ORDER singled BY iid) INTO '$output';
```

However, I am not a fan of this solution -- it's too many lines and new relations for such a simple operation. What is really needed is a way to combine two bags into one.  Pig apparently doesn't provide this (though if it does, please answer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661389/how-to-combine-concat-two-bags-in-pig-latin)).  You could write a simple UDF to do this, though:

```
public class MERGE extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        DataBag b = new DefaultDataBag();
        try {
            if (input != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
                    b.addAll((DataBag) input.get(i));
        } catch (Exception e) { return null; }
        return b;
    }
}
```

With this UDF in hand, the solution becomes:

```
a = load '$input' as (iid:int, field:chararray, v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
b = load '$data' as (iid:int, field:chararray, v1:chararray, v2:chararray, v3:chararray);
c = FOREACH (COGROUP a BY iid, b BY iid) GENERATE group AS iid, MERGE(a,b) AS bag;
out = FOREACH c {
    uniq = DISTINCT bag;
    GENERATE iid, FLATTEN(bag);
};
STORE (ORDER out BY iid) INTO '$output';
```

Another advantage of this approach is that if you have several inputs, you won't need to do several `FOREACH`s after the `COGROUP`.  Just add more arguments to `MERGE`:

```
c = FOREACH (COGROUP a BY iid, b BY iid, ..., z BY iid)
    GENERATE group AS iid, MERGE(a,b,...,z) AS bag;
```

Comment: This is great, Winnie! I will try it out and let u know! Thank you so much for your advices, it's very helpful and i really appreciate it! :)

Comment: winnie, i used the first approach which worked perfect. I just tried the 2nd approach, but got error on the line of the MERGE code as follows. Do you have any idea about it? [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file /home/admuser/merge.pig, line 11, column 48>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '('

Comment: You have a syntax error (not that you didn't know that).  Pig's error messages can be quite cryptic, so it's hard to say what your issue is. Your best bet would be to post a new question specific to this error, with the code that is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

This one here should solve your problem:

```
f1 = LOAD '/user/hadoop/f1' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id_f1:int, key_f1:chararray, value_f1:chararray);
f2 = LOAD '/user/hadoop/f2' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id_f2:int, key_f2:chararray, value_f2:chararray);
f3 = JOIN f1 by id_f1 LEFT OUTER, f2 BY id_f2;
f4 = FOREACH f3 GENERATE id_f1, key_f1, value_f1;
f5 = FOREACH f3 GENERATE id_f2, key_f2, value_f2;
f6 = UNION f4, f5;
f7 = DISTINCT f6;
f8 = ORDER f7 BY $0;
DUMP f8;
```

Comment: This will also throw away records from A which do not have a match in B, so it would be better to do `f3 = JOIN f1 BY id_f1 LEFT OUTER, f2 BY id_f2;`